# Android Conductor ArcMotion example

Tags: android, android-layout, conductor

I'm trying to understand demo example from https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor library.

Motion looks like this

[image]

This is the code, responsible for animation

```
public class ArcFadeMoveChangeHandler extends TransitionChangeHandler {
    public ArcFadeMoveChangeHandler() { }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    protected Transition getTransition(@NonNull ViewGroup container, View from, View to, boolean isPush) {
        TransitionSet transition = new TransitionSet()
                .setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_SEQUENTIAL)
                .addTransition(new Fade(Fade.OUT))
                .addTransition(new TransitionSet().addTransition(new ChangeBounds()).addTransition(new ChangeClipBounds()).addTransition(new ChangeTransform()))
                .addTransition(new Fade(Fade.IN));

        transition.setPathMotion(new ArcMotion());

        return transition;
    }
}
```

How does it know, that motion should be performed for FAB? How can I perform arc motion for FAB, but set all the rest elements on screen to FadeOut?

Answer (score 0):

### How does it know, that motion should be performed for FAB?

Look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/package-summary.html) for `Fade`

> This transition tracks changes to the visibility of target views in
>   the start and end scenes and fades views in or out when they become
>   visible or non-visible.

and documentation for `ChangeBounds` (and other similar classes):

> This transition captures the layout bounds of target views before and
>   after the scene change and animates those changes during the
>   transition.

So Fab (and text) is not faded because it's shared element in the conductors demo and it's present in the next layout with the same "android:transitionName" in both layouts. Everything else changed visibility so it's faded.

### How can I perform arc motion for FAB, but set all the rest elements on screen to FadeOut?

Simply remove `android:transitionName` from textView. I think Conductor might do something under the hood (i.e. manually add `transitionName`), so if removing `transitionName` doesn't help, try to remove/change ids so it's not the same in both layouts.